# Why does moving a value into a closure still have the error message "cannot borrow immutable local variable as mutable"?

Tags: rust

In the code below, I explicitly force the `name` from the `main` function to be moved into the closure, and everything works just fine:

```
fn main() {
    let name = String::from("Alice");

    let welcome = || {
        let mut name = name;
        name += " and Bob";
        println!("Welcome, {}", name);
    };

    welcome();
}
```

I would have thought that adding a `move` to the beginning of the closure would accomplish the same thing, and result in the value being moved and the creation of a `FnOnce`:

```
fn main() {
    let name = String::from("Alice");

    let welcome = move || {
        name += " and Bob";
        println!("Welcome, {}", name);
    };

    welcome();
}
```

Instead, however, I get the error message:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable local variable `welcome` as mutable
 --> main.rs:9:5
  |
4 |     let welcome = move || {
  |         ------- help: make this binding mutable: `mut welcome`
...
9 |     welcome();
  |     ^^^^^^^ cannot borrow mutably

error[E0596]: cannot borrow captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure as mutable
 --> main.rs:5:9
  |
5 |         name += " and Bob";
  |         ^^^^
```

What's the correct way to think about `move` on a closure in this case?

Comment: Please note the compiler *told you what to do*: `help: make this binding mutable: \`mut welcome\``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would have thought that adding a `move` to the beginning of the closure would accomplish the same thing, …

It kind of does the same thing.  You just forgot to declare `name` and `welcome` as mutable. This code works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let mut name = String::from("Alice");

    let mut welcome = move || {
        name += " and Bob";
        println!("Welcome, {}", name);
    };

    welcome();
}
```

Both versions of the closure result in `name` being moved into the closure.  In the first version, this is implicitly caused by consuming `name` inside the closure. The second version does not consume `name`, but uses the `move` keyword to force the move.

> … and result in the value being moved and the creation of a `FnOnce`.

Moving a value into a closure does not make it `FnOnce`. If a closure *consumes* a captured value, it becomes `FnOnce`, since it obviously can do this only once. Thus, the first version of the closure is `FnOnce`, since it consumes `name`. The clousre above is `FnMut`, and can be called multiple times.  Calling it twice results in the output

```
Welcome, Alice and Bob
Welcome, Alice and Bob and Bob
```

(I used the function trait names somewhat sloppily above. In fact, *every* closure implements `FnOnce`, since every closure can be called at least once.  Some closures can be called multiple times, so they are `FnMut` in addition.  And some closures that can be called multiple times don't alter their captured state, so they are `Fn` in addition to the other two traits.)

Comment: While the rewrite you've provided (adding the `mut`s) does compile, it's semantically different from the first version of the code I provided. In particular, in the first version, calling `welcome()` a second time is an error due to usage of a moved value. I realize that in this case I can mutable borrow the values instead, but I'm trying to understand why `move` doesn't force the value to be moved into the closure.

Comment: Try to print `name` variable after `welcome`. It will result in compile-time error, because of `move` keyword. You can calling `welcome` multiple times, because it is `FnMut` and it captures the `name` variable. [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=f1bb59a9dae591b95c5c291eb38d0ab0) code from the [rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/closures/input_parameters.html) may clarify it

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman `move` _does_ force `name` to be moved into the closure.  The first version also moves the value into the closure, but then consumes it inside the closure. A closure that consumes a captured value can only be called once.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I added a few sentences to this answer – hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thanks @SvenMarnach, this helped. The piece that was alluding me was the distinction between *moving* a value and *consuming* a value. The link to Rust by Example was elucidating as well Artemiy.